# Compare Items in NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsset

My `NSArray` contains a day of the week followed by space and a number.  The array looks like this:

```
(
    "Monday 1 - Rapids",
    "Monday 2 - Durango Shopping",
    "Monday - Train"
)
```

What I need to do is to scan through the array for the one with the highest number, and delete everything else.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this.

You could use `componentsSeparatedByString: @" "` to break each item into words and then take intValue of the second item in each resulting array. That would be easy, but use rather a lot of temporary memory and probably be kind of slow.

You could write code using NSScanner to extract the item between the first and second spaces.

You could write a regular expression that would match on the second word and return an empty room sting if it's not a number. (You'd make the number a "capture group".)

Answer (score 1):

step 1. use `componentsSeparatedByString: @" - "`
step 2. if first item exist then use `componentsSeparatedByString: @" "` than use the first item for a key
step 3. create a mutabDictionary 
step 4. compare the number and record the highest index